# For each line in file passing argument - Batch Scripting

Tags: bash, scripting, batch-file

I'm trying to convert a series of bash scripts to batch files. I'm having the following issue with one part of a script, the part performs the following:

Connect to network share, for each folder with a certain root name find the latest version, copy the .zip inside to a local location. It should loop this method through all folders found in a directory, here is the bash version of this:

```
for f in /xxx/xxx/xxx.xxx.game_android*
do
        cd $f
        ls | sed 's/_//g' | sed 's/test.sh//g' | sed 's/plist.txt//g' | sed 's/^...//' > $dir/res/temp_list.txt
        sort $dir/res/temp_list.txt > $dir/res/temp_list_sorted.txt
        rm $dir/res/temp_list.txt
        export atom=`tail -n1 $dir/res/temp_list_sorted.txt`
        export final=`ls | grep "$atom"`
        rm $dir/res/temp_list_sorted.txt
        cd $final
        echo "Copying atom: $atom"
        cp *.zip $dir/res/sb5-games/
        echo "Copying File: $f"
done
```

This works well, but when trying to convert it to batch I'm faced with lots of issues. I was able to install GnuWin32 CoreUtils, Sed, and Grep so I'm able to use all the same tools, but the actual process of looping through all folders in a directory isn't working.

My question: what format of the FOR command would I use to loop through all folders in a directory with a wildcard, then how would I execute the series of commands I need to on each folder?

Thanks.

Comment: If you installed all that, why don't you install Bash?

Comment: Didn't know you could... I'll look into it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all folders in `WhateverDirectory` using the following construct in your batch file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /AD /B WhateverDirectory' ) DO (
  PUSHD "WhateverDirectory\%%F"
  ECHO You are now in subdir %%F of WhateverDirectory
  ECHO and can do your stuff here
  ECHO etcetera
  POPD
)
```

A good batch guide is http://www.ss64.com/nt/ or checkout [What is a good windows batch scripting reference guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18254/1380680)